# How to store value of a non-standard HTTP request header to be used in an Apache If conditional

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, environment-variables, http-headers

My server will be receiving a non-standard HTTP request named EmployeeID that I want to use to determine access rights to certain directories on the server.  How can I store the value of the incoming non-standard HTTP request header so that it can be used in an If conditional using Apache directives?

After searching online for quite some time I came up with the following where I attempt to save the header to an environment variable using RewriteRule so that I could access the value of the variable later for the comparison.  Unfortunately, I have only met frustration instead of success.

```
<Direcory "\Apache24\htdocs\usrs">
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule .* - [E=EmployeeID:%{HTTP:EmployeeID}]
   <If "{Request_URI} != /%{EmployeeID}/">
      Deny from all
   </If>
</Directory">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use the [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) apache directive. Possibly:

```
SetEnvIf EmployeeId "^(.+)$" eid=$1
<Directory "\Apache24\htdocs\usrs">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=eid
</Directory>
```

Look at the [Prevent "Image Theft"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html#image-theft) example, I think that might do something similar to what you need.